# SQL check if thread timestamp is newer than reply timestamp in JOIN Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm kinda new to SQL joins and was thinking on going full overkill probably.
What I want to do is join my four tables together.

What I want to accomplish is that I want all the information from category, and I want it to be matched to the replies with the newest timestamp and then I want to join the t.title which t.id matches r.thread_id

```
SELECT c.*, t.id, t.title, r.timestamp, u.id, u.username
FROM forum_category AS c 
LEFT JOIN forum_threads AS t ON (c.id = t.category_id)
LEFT JOIN forum_replies AS r ON (t.id = r.thread_id 
     AND r.timestamp = 
     (
         SELECT timestamp 
         FROM forum_replies 
         ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
    ))
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (r.user_id = u.id)
GROUP BY c.id
```

As it is now this code *seems* to work, not having tested it alot.

However I need to expand it to check if t.timestamp is newer than latest r.timestamp and JOIN that one instead then. with the t.title, t.timestamp and t.user_id.

So if a thread is newer than the latest reply.
I know I could make the first post a reply and solve it that way. But I'm not doing that right now if it's possible to solve in the SQL statement.

SQL layout imgur here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkRIX.jpg

forum_category:

[image: thread table]

forum_threads:
[image: thread table]
forum_replies:
[image: reply table]

Comment: `SELECT c.*, t.id, t.title, r.timestamp, u.id, u.username...GROUP BY c.id` looks like a invalid SQL query to me.. https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Answer (score 1):

One helpful technique is to use Subqueries to break up the mental logic of what your query is trying to do.  Basically, a subquery takes the place of a regular table in any query.

So, first up, we need to get the most recent time stamp in the replies for each thread:

```
select thread_id, max(timestamp) as LatestReply
from forum_replies
group by thread_id
```

Let's call this our MostRecentThreadSubquery.  So, it would let us do something like:

```
select * from
forum_threads t
LEFT JOIN
(
    select thread_id, max(timestamp) as LatestReply
    from forum_replies
    group by thread_id
) as MostRecentThreadSubquery
on t.thread_id = MostRecentThreadSubquery.thread_id
```

Make sense?  We're no longer joining the forum_threads table against the forum_replies table - we've made a subquery to help us list the most recent reply for each thread id.

Now, we add the SQL CASE statement, to get something like:

```
select
    thread_id,
    CASE WHEN t.timestamp > MostRecentThreadSubquery.LatestReply
        THEN t.timestamp
        ELSE MostRecentThreadSubquery.LatestReply
    END as MostRecentTimestamp
from -- ... the rest of that earlier SQL statement
```

Okay, so now we've got a query that, for every thread_id, has the most recent timestamp - whether that's from the forum_replies or from the forum_threads table.

... and you guessed it.  We're going to make it another subquery.  Let's call it our MostRecentPerThread

```
select *
from forum_category AS c
LEFT JOIN
(
    -- ... that previous query ...
) as MostRecentPerThread
on c.thread_id = MostRecentPerThread.thread_id
```

Make sense?  You're using subqueries as a way of logically breaking down your query into smaller components.  You no longer have one gigantic query.  You've got a small subquery that simply gets the timestamp of the most recent reply.  You've got a small subquery that compares that first subquery to the threads table to get the most recent timestamp.  And you've got a main query that uses the second subquery to merge it with the categories table.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll test some and get back to what I get. The first problem is that the first query I need the user_id from max(timestamp) to

Comment: Added a new query into the second one but getting a SQLerror *SELECT * FROM
forum_threads AS t
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT thread_id, user_id, timestamp as LatestReply
 FROM forum_replies r1
 WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM forum_replies r2 WHERE r1.thread_id = r2.thread_id)
 GROUP BY thread_id;
) AS MostRecentThreadSubquery
ON t.id = MostRecentThreadSubquery.thread_id* #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
the AS before MostRecentThreadSubquery is highlighted

Comment: I think you've got a rogue semicolon right before the end of MostRecentThreadSubquery

Comment: Really thanks for the reply I'm getting most things up and working. One problem though is when the a thread have no reply so that the forum replies timestamp is null. I think that's where my problem is that I can't handle null

Comment: ISNULL can help out with that.  Or you might just need to flip the comparison when checking the timestamps (3 > NULL and 3 < NULL are both false - nothing is ever greater than NULL, or less than NULL.)

Comment: Cool, this is what I got now https://pastebin.com/ZxHjPmg5 problem is category 1 has 3 entries http://prntscr.com/j6511t  I tried using GROUP BY but that only takes the first one and not the one with the most recent timestamp

Comment: And is there anyway to include number of replies in the query. I've tried adding it to the first query with no luck. *SELECT COUNT(*) as num_replies FROM forum_replies GROUP BY thread_id*

Comment: Okay, again, you need to break it into steps.  You're after: most recent reply timestamp for each thread, the number of replies for each thread, and the user who most recently replied.  Great - how many can you get in one pass?  All but the user - select TID,max(Timestamp),count(*) from replies group by TID.  Then, join this subquery/pseudo-table up against the replies table, matching on TID+Timestamp to get the matching user for each of your entries.  Finally, use this combined result as the thing you match up against your forum_threads.

Comment: Okey, count was easier than expected must have missed something the first time. However the earlier question is still a mystery. This is what I got at the moment https://pastebin.com/pM4wHzck but I can't group by c.id I tried order by MostRecentTimestamp and Limit by 1 also but doesn't seem to do what I want either